# Flickr public api using jsonp in react

Tags: reactjs, jsonp, flickr, codepen

I'm trying to display images with the Flickr public api using a jsonp request in react. I keep getting different issues and don't know how to make this work. I'm also using Codepen and I have errors like "Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonFlickrFeed is not defined". I have seen working examples but I'm new to jsonp so don't really know how to integrate this with react

[Full code is here](https://codepen.io/jfe84/pen/ReRLvd?editors=0111)

```
getItems() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {
         "tags": this.state.search,
         "format": "json"
      }
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed [codepen link](https://codepen.io/trkaplan/pen/EdNPeB).

Steps to fix this problem:

- As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49708208/458679), add `nojsoncallback=1` parameter to the API
  URL to receive a pure json object.
- Remove `dataType:jsonp` property
  from ajax settings not to get MIME type error, because we no more
  receive a JSONP response.
- Put your callback function in `.done()`
  method
- If you preview the code on codepen, you will get a CORS error. Run your code on your local environment or install a CORS Browser plugin to get rid of this error.

Comment: thanks, looking at the code I have been so close before. I had that CORS error but didn't know how to fix, I did the .done() but nothing was happening, did the nojsoncallback=1 as well but I never got to make this work. Thanks a lot